# Derivative of a vector function. Misunderstanding

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Say $f(z) = g^2(z, z^2) + z^4$. What is $f'(z)$?

I thought to use the chain rule but I am not sure if I'm right. I mean

$$f'(z) = \dfrac{d g^2}{dz} \dfrac{dz}{dz} + \dfrac{d g^2}{dz}\dfrac{dz^2}{dz} + 4z^3$$

Is this correct?

Also, $\dfrac{d g^2}{dz}$ would be $2g(z, z^2) g'(z, z^2)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by $g'(z, z^2)$. Note that $g(x,y)$ is a function of two-variables, therefore, again by the chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dz}g(z, z^2)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(z,z^2)\cdot 1+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(z,z^2)\cdot 2z.$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align*}f'(z) &= \dfrac{d (g^2(z,z^2))}{dz} + 4z^3\\
&=2g(z,z^2)\cdot\frac{d}{dz}g(z, z^2) + 4z^3\\
&=
2g(z,z^2)\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(z,z^2)+2g(z,z^2)\cdot\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(z,z^2)\cdot 2z+ 4z^3.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you! It puzzled me the expression $g^2(z, z^2)$ for it looked like a function in two components, but one variable, hence I got a bit stuck